# What name do you call teamtreehouse.com and happyapps.io website graphic design

Tags: html, css, graphics

What name do you call https://teamtreehouse.com/ and http://www.happyapps.io/ style of their web designs
I having been seeing this style of web design interface and I am in love with it. But I need to know the name so I can research on it and start applying it.
Even paypal is also implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

That's Flat Design I think, but you should have a look to Google's Material Design, it's very nice looking and everything is very well explained on their website : https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html